# PHP Array Undefined Offset, Even Though The Code Executes

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to extract some variables from my `REQUEST_URI`:

```
liquidfinger.com/key1-value1/key2-value2/key3-value3
```

I want to transform these values into a php associative array. My code is as follows:

```
$pState = [];
$stateString = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1);//remove leading slash
if($stateString){
    $statePairs = explode("/",$stateString);
    foreach($statePairs as $statePair){
        $statePairArray = explode("-",$statePair);
        $pState[$statePairArray[0]] = $statePairArray[1];
    }
}
```

The `$pState` array is being created correctly and I can `echo` all the keys and values. However, I am getting an `error_log`:

> Undefined offset: 1

I am even getting an `error_log` when there are no key-value pairs, so the `IF` statement shouldn't be executed, but possibly that is a characteristic of the `error_log`?

Okay, just to recap, the code was working but I was getting error messages. Further tests yielded the following:

```
url: www.liquidfinger.com
print_r($pState): Array ( )
[11-Mar-2016 10:01:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/adamglynsmith/public_html/index.php on line 20


url: http://www.liquidfinger.com/user-2/tab-browseAll/marker-101
print_r($pState): Array ( [user] => 2 [tab] => browseAll [marker] => 101 )
print_r($statePairArray): Array ( [0] => user [1] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => tab     [1] => browseAll ) Array ( [0] => marker [1] => 101 )
[11-Mar-2016 10:14:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/adamglynsmith/public_html/index.php on line 20
[11-Mar-2016 10:14:43 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/adamglynsmith/public_html/index.php on line 20
```

Since I have spent quite enough time on it and since I ultimately wanted to end up with a JavaScript array, I solved - or avoided - the problem by using the php to construct a string for the JavaScript like so:

```
    $stateString = str_replace("/","', ",$stateString);//get rid of slashes
    $stateString = str_replace("-",":'",$stateString);//get rid of dashes
    $stateString .= "'";//add final single quote
    <script>
        jState = {<?php echo $stateString; ?>};
    </script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So `print_r($statePairs)` and check.

Comment: explode returns an array even if there was nothing to explode - you just get an array with the original string in it. you're just assuming that you exploded your $statePair properly and produced 2 entries ([0] and [1]). in other words, `var_dump($statePairArray, $statePairs)` and make sure your inputs are correct.

Comment: Which line does the `Undefined offset` point to?

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not guard your code implicitly, so you have to do some extra work to make sure you're actually able to do the correct thing:

```
$pState = [];
$stateString = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1);//remove leading slash
if($stateString){
    $statePairs = explode("/",$stateString);
    if (count($statePairs)) >= 1 {  // Technically unnecessary unless you want to log the fact you didn't find anything.
        foreach($statePairs as $statePair){
            $statePairArray = explode("-",$statePair);
            if (count($statePairArray) == 2) {  // Found two and only two elements
                $pState[$statePairArray[0]] = $statePairArray[1];
            } else {
                //It is very helpful in log statements to include the values of things that produced unexpected results
                Log.warn("Invalid key-pair found for statePairArray=" + $statePairArray);
            }
        }
    } else {
        LOG.warn("No state pairs found for stateString=" + $stateString);//Or some other appropriate log or exception
    }
}
```

[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) may return an empty array if there is nothing to explode on. Therefore you need to check and take an appropriate action if it isn't there.